# Pattern matching over an AST struct in the compiler

Tags: pattern-matching, rust

So I am trying to pattern match on a struct.  This particular struct is made-up of a number of enums, which contain pointers to enums, or at its most basic level, a vector un-signed 8-bytes.  I would like to work with the vector, however would like to know if it is possible to pattern match my way to the vec.

```
ast::ExprUnary(ast::UnDeref, ref exprs) =>{
        let pat = match exprs.node {

            ast::ExprLit(ast::Lit(codemap::Spanned(ast::LitBinary(string),innerspan))) => {
                 //stuff to string
                 //primary issue here is that these enums, which ExprLit is 
                 //comprised of, do not pattern match correctly
            }
            _ => //other stuff
        };
```

upon compiling this code, I receive the following two errors,

```
unresolved enum variant, struct or const `Spanned`
unresolved enum variant, struct or const `Lit`
```

both of these enums exist within ast, however, I do not know why they are are unresolved in this particular context.  Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the time to create a [minimal, compilable, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Specifically for Rust, it's good to have something that can demonstrate the same error on [the Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/). This helps you better understand your own question, and helps answerers better get a grasp of the problem (and avoid missed guesses, like the answer you have now).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things are going awry here.

1. [`ast::Lit`](http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/ast/type.Lit.html) is just a type alias of [`codemap::Spanned`](http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/codemap/struct.Spanned.html), not an enum or an enum variant. So you don't need to specify both, but you must specify either.
2. [`ast::ExprLit`](http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/ast/enum.Expr_.html) is an enum tuple variant containing a [`P<Lit>`](http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/ptr/struct.P.html). So you need to destructure the `P` by using `P(inner)`

   - At least I remember doing `P`-destructuring this way. The docs say otherwise. If it doesn't work, you need to dereference this and add another inner match for the content
3. [`codemap::Spanned`](http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/codemap/struct.Spanned.html) is a struct, not a tuple struct, which means you cannot match on its fields by position, but you must destructure the fields by name like so:

   ```
   let codemap::Spanned {
       node: innernode,
       span: innerspan,
   } = some_spanned;
   ```

In total I believe your match should look something along the lines of

```
let pat = match exprs.node {
    ast::ExprLit( P( codemap::Spanned {
        node: ast::LitBinary(string),
        span: innerspan,
    })) => {
        //stuff to string
        //primary issue here is that these enums, which ExprLit is 
        //comprised of, do not pattern match correctly
    }
    _ => { //other stuff }
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, really concise and informative.  I really appreciate you explaining things that I've just been overlooking for the past few days.

Answer (score 0):

I used to write code like this, but it gets tiresome. Now I just `use syntax::ast::*` and leave off all the `ast::`s in the code. This will also take care of the `Lit` (as it is in `syntax::ast`)

I cannot say for sure what the actual issue is, because your code is incomplete, but look at https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/blob/master/src/len_zero.rs for a successfully compiling example.

Comment: I don't believe that this is an importing error, as I already have a call to `codemap::spanned` earlier in the code, and no such errors, arose.  Additionally, I attempted to add the use statements, but the error did not change

Comment: I'm wary of glob imports, so I've found it useful to just use them in a small scope - like just the function. [Example](http://is.gd/j3vVav)

Comment: @TylerHarden fair enough, but as you gave an incomplete code snippet, we can only guess what the actual error may be.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Usually I also try and avoid glob imports, and they have actually bitten me once (incidentially at the len_zero lint), but when writing lints we get so many ast::this and ast::that that just glob importing is the saner solution here.